# How to share external hard drive over wifi?

Tags: networking, samba

I have an external Hard Drive connected to my pc running ubuntu 15.10. I wanted to share the data on it over my home wifi network to access it using android phones. I tried various methods using samba but non of them worked for me. Please provide step vise instructions to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Samba is not directly required for your Ubuntu to Android file sharing.

If you create a normal folder on your external drive and set it up for sharing using the built-in file sharing permissions of Ubuntu. This is found by right-clicking on the desired folder in the Ubuntu 'Files' program and clicking on 'Local Network Share'. This opens a pop-up box that allows you to initiate the 'Folder Sharing'. So long as your network is secured, allowing 'Guest Access' on this screen would make it easier to access from the Android phones.

Once the folder sharing is setup from Ubuntu, you can navigate to this folder from your Android devices. I personally use 'ES File Explorer' for this. on 'ES File Explorer' you can navigate to the 'Network' tab and search for connected computers using the icon at the top of the screen. Once the desired computer has been located, you can click on it to initiate the connection and provide access to the shared folder.

Hope This Helps,

T3CHI5